# order by field with more than 10000 ids

Tags: sql, field, sql-order-by

I need to do specific ordering with use of order by field.

```
select * from table order by field(id,3,4,1,2.......upto 10000 ids)
```

As the ordering required is not gettable from SQL then how much it affect as per performance and is it feasible to do?

Updates from the comments:

- Ordering depends on user and category IDs and can be anything the user wants.
- The ordering specification changes (about) daily.

So, we need a custom ordering that depends on the user and category and this ordering needs to change daily.

Comment: Do you mean up to 10000 columns?  Ordering by a field is not difficult; build an index on that field and you're done.

Comment: @bdares: I hope jit doesn't mean 10000 columns. @jit, do you mean that you have 10000 rows and you want to order them in some custom format that doesn't depend on the `id` in any clean and simply way?

Comment: yes @mu is too short got me right...

Comment: If you want to set some sort of custom order on your records, why not add a column to hold this order and build an index on that?

Comment: order is user specific and generating when we fetching and displaying result per day per user.....

Comment: @jit: Does this mean that each day you retrieve a list of records for each user sorted by date?

Comment: @tobias86: I think jit means that each client gets to specify their own ordering (chosen by them in whatever way they want) every day and that ordering would be used for that client's queries until they chose a new way of ordering things.

Comment: @mu: If that is the case then I agree with @bdares's suggestion. Best would be to add an extra column to store the order.

Comment: @tobias86: That would be a mess if you had 20 clients accessing the same table, you'd need 20 extra columns and that seems a lot uglier to me than 20 extra tables. Neither approach is exactly wonderful but, well, reality and business requirements and all that. Using an extra column makes sense if there is only one strange ordering but I'm reading the comments as saying that there are many strange orderings (one per client).

Comment: @mu: I hear you. But surely, if they are retrieving a list per user, it stands to reason that each record is associated with a particular user somehow, hopefully via some 'userid' field. One could then easily keep track of each user's ordering by using the `userid` and `order` fields together. But yes, if that is not the case, then this is going to be an interesting exercise... :)

Comment: actually the order is changing for per user per day per category(18). and worse thing that order need to be created from separte stored procedure or need to generate from php and pass to sql. but if we pass those ordered ids in order by field is it feasible?

Comment: @tobias86: I updated my answer with a single extra table approach, I sort of got locked into "extra tables" thinking and took it a bit too far.

Comment: I merged some notes from the comments into the question to, hopefully, clarify what's going on here.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to put your ordering in a separate table (called `ordering_table` in this example):

```
 id | position
----+----------
  1 | 11
  2 | 42
  3 | 23
 etc.
```

The above would mean "put an `id` of 1 at position 11, 2 at position 42, 3 at position 23, ...". Then you can join that ordering table in:

```
SELECT t.id, t.col1, t.col2
FROM some_table t
JOIN ordering_table o ON (t.id = o.id)
ORDER BY o.position
```

Where `ordering_table` is the table (as above) that defines your strange ordering. This approach simply represents your ordering function as a table (any function with a finite domain is, essentially, just a table after all).

This "ordering table" approach should work fine as long as the ordering table is complete.

If you only need this strange ordering in one place then you could merge the `position` column into your main table and add `NOT NULL` and `UNIQUE` constraints on that column to make sure you cover everything and have a consistent ordering.

Further commenting indicates that you want different orderings for different users and categories and that the ordering will change on a daily basis. You could make separate tables for each condition (which would lead to a combinatorial explosion) or, as Mikael Eriksson and ypercube suggest, add a couple more columns to the ordering table to hold the user and category:

```
CREATE TABLE ordering_table (
    thing_id    INT NOT NULL,
    position    INT NOT NULL,
    user_id     INT NOT NULL,
    category_id INT NOT NULL
);
```

The `thing_id`, `user_id`, and `category_id` would be foreign keys to their respective tables and you'd probably want to index all the columns in `ordering_table` but a couple minutes of looking at the query plans would be worthwhile to see if the indexes get used would be worthwhile. You could also make all four columns the primary key to avoid duplicates. Then, the lookup query would be something like this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.col1, t.col2
FROM some_table t
LEFT JOIN ordering_table o
     ON (t.id = o.thing_id AND o.user_id = $user AND o.category_id = $cat)
ORDER BY COALESCE(o.position, 99999)
```

Where `$user` and `$cat` are the user and category IDs (respectively). Note the change to a LEFT JOIN and the addition of COALESCE to allow for missing rows in `ordering_table`, these changes will push anything that doesn't have a specified position in the order to the bottom of the list rather than removing them from the results completely.

Comment: @jit: So one ordering table for each user and the ordering table gets updated every day.

Comment: If you add a UserID column to the ordering_table you don't need to have one table for every user. Users can maintain the separate ordering in the same table.

Comment: @jit: So, you just add two more columns in this table: `userid` and `categoryid`.

Comment: @Mikael, @ypercube, @jit: I think ypercube's idea of user and category columns to the ordering table makes more sense than a bunch of separate tables so I'll update the answer to reflect that. I got mentally locked into "separate tables" and kept going with it when I should have stepped back a bit; but that's what comments are for.

Comment: MAke it a temp table that is built when the user specifies the order if the order is different every time. Otherwise make it a permanant table that also has the user_id/category_id. If you use a permant table, you need to set up a way that new records get added as new records get added to the original table.

Comment: Finishing comment:Typically this type of task is done through a trigger.  To make it simple, new records woudl get a position number much higher than the expected number of records that need to be ordered. SO if there would normally be 20 records per user/category use a number like 999999999 as the position for those not specified yet. This saves having to calculate postion on the fly when records are added for each separate user.

Comment: @HELGEM: We know that the ordering is updated ~daily and has ~1e4 entries so I think a permanent table makes sense. I went with a LEFT JOIN and COALESCE rather than a trigger to deal with missing entries. It is hard to say which approach would be better without more information. The main idea is the represent the ordering function as a table and we seem to agree that this makes sense.